# Some of deleted occurrence of recurring event doesn't comes under EXDATE

Tags: icalendar, caldav, icloud-api

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  

BEGIN:VEVENT  
SUMMARY:Test 
TRANSP:OPAQUE  
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;EMAIL=a@icloud.com;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;   
ROLE=CHAIR;CN=a:/aMzg2Mzc2MTQzODYzNzYxNBljuJkfI_9Sr7UoBKqc9uB4hzRY_BLyjaYyqorZZI2N/principal/  
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;EMAIL=jag@icloud.com;   
PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;X-CALENDARSERVER-DTSTAMP=20170629T173339Z;CN=jag:/aNDM3NzY5NTU0Mzc3Njk1NYeGQfswrR4swF97f86hXgEy6_Ht3psyYKknwa5ed2iV/principal/  
UID:4CF18F94-CFB0-4EC8-8CA3-13BD88BE3009  
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170530T183000  
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170530T220000  
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY  
EXDATE;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170711T183000  
EXDATE;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170627T183000  
EXDATE;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170620T183000  
END:VEVENT  

BEGIN:VEVENT  
SUMMARY:Test  
TRANSP:OPAQUE  
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;EMAIL=a@icloud.com;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;   
ROLE=CHAIR;CN=a:   /aMzg2Mzc2MTQzODYzNzYxNBljuJkfI_9Sr7UoBKqc9uB4hzRY_BLyjaYyqorZZI2N/principal/  
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;EMAIL=jag@icloud.com;   
PARTSTAT=DECLINED;X-CALENDARSERVER-DTSTAMP=20170629T173339Z;
CN=jag:/aNDM3NzY5NTU0Mzc3Njk1NYeGQfswrR4swF97f86hXgEy6_Ht3psyYKknwa5ed2iV/principal/  
UID:4CF18F94-CFB0-4EC8-8CA3-13BD88BE3009  
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170606T183000  
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170606T220000  
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20170606T183000  
END:VEVENT  

END:VCALENDAR
```

Here, I have weekly recurring meeting for every Tuesday from 6:30 PM to 10:00 PM. I have deleted the single occurrence for 06/06/2017. But when I fetch meetings it gives deleted occurrence i.e 06/06/2017 6:30 PM to 10:30 PM which it shouldn't be. While 20/06, 27/06 and 11/07 comes in ex date which is fine. My question is that why 06/06 is not in ex date even after deletion like other deleted dates ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: How were these events created? Did you create them, or did a caldav server do it?

Comment: I haven't created via code. I have created them directly on iCloud.com  but when I am fetching them I am getting this ics in return.

Comment: None of your questions are about ical.net so I re-tagged them icloud.